# How to read a file using sed starting from a specific line number and replace values and output to new file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file where I want to read starting at line number 426 and ending at 2372.  Within those lines I want to replace `, ,` with a new line character and output this to a new file.

I have tried the following:

```
sed -n '426,2372p' input.txt > $tmpSrcFile
```

which works grabbing that section and outputting it but when I add the replace I can't get it to work:

```
sed -n '426,2372ps/:, ,:/\n/g' input.txt > $tmpSrcFile
```

Comment: Try `sed -n '426,2372{s/:, ,:/\n/gp}' input.txt > $tmpSrcFile`

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Define 'didn't work': what _did_ it do and how did that differ from the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

For the given input file:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
```

This `sed` invocation seems to replace and print only within a line range:

```
$ sed -n '3,4{s/,/^/gp}' input; printf "END\n"
3^
4^
END
```

Even when the replacement is a newline:

```
$ sed -n '3,4{s/,/\n/gp}' input; printf "END\n"
3

4

END
```